# How to chaining actions in Redux and React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am new to React, Redux and JS overall. I want to know how can I chain actions in a component? On a listing screen, my application retrieves user's Geo Position then it fetching api url with current long and lat.

I made it with time out. But I see it's a risky way.

```
import {
  aFetch,
  aGetPosition,
} from '../../actions';

import { API_URL } from '../../config/ApiEndpoints';

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.aGetPosition();
    setTimeout(() => {
      const { latitude, longitude } = this.props.position.data.coords;
      const url = `${API_URL}=${latitude},${longitude}`;

      this.props.aFetch(url);
    }, 1000);
  }

  render(){...}
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    position: state.position,
    items: state.items,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { aFetch, aGetPosition })(App);
```

Is possible to make it using .then() or something equal?

Comment: yes https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk

Comment: Either [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) or [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga) (my personal preference) should help you achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need the method `componentWillReceiveProps()`. The [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) provide a good explanation about it and other methods in the lifecycle of a component.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this approach because then you'll need to do comparisons on all new props to make sure no infinite loops are caused. It's better to put that logic inside the action

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you'll want to dispatch your redux actions. This is possible by using a `mapDispatchToProps` function, which will be the 2nd parameter in your `connect` function (instead of a plain object with your actions, which is what you have now). Docs on implementing redux within your React containers, including dispatching actions from your container: http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html#implementing-container-components

To handle async actions and chaining actions, you'll likely want to use a middleware to help you, such as redux-thunk. Doc link: http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html#async-action-creators (I recommend reading this whole page, but the link will go directly to the section for redux-thunk).